# How to set Foreign Key constraint for 2 tables?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, in-memory-tables

I have 2 tables in SQL Server 2016: Master->Detail.
The Detail table I have migrated to Memory Optimized.
But when I back set the Foreign Key constraint I receive the:

```
Msg 10778, Level 16, State 0, Line 32
Foreign key relationships between memory optimized tables and non-memory optimized tables are not supported.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

How to connect again these Master (Disk) table and Detail (Memory Optimized) Table?

Comment: You cannot do this, they both need to be memory tables or both not

Comment: Yes, I understand it, but I migrate only part of db tables. How to be in cases like that? Leave these 2 tables disconnected?

Comment: Or migrate both of them at the same time? This is one of the limitations, there is nothing you can do

Comment: No one can answer your question now. You made a decision that has a significant impact. Do you want the database engine to enforce referential integrity (RI)? Then change your tables. If not, then you and your code assume responsibility for RI. Since you are asking and you seem unsure, maybe you should go back and review the decision to migrate just one table.

Comment: @SMor, you are right, but in the real task I migrate 10 tables and 90 leave as they are disk tables. In any case I have a problem on the limit between disk tables and InMemory sub-hierarchy: the disk table has relation to the migrated root table.

Comment: You made a decision. That decision has consequences. Again - only you can decide what do do now. You can't use the engine to enforce referential integrity (RI) with this decision. So it is your choice - change the tables to be consistent and use foreign keys or enforce RI programatically.

Comment: @SMor Answer as an Answer I ill mark it. Thnx.